# Composer require looking to craft/plugins/[plugin] directory but throws runtime error?

Tags: plugins, install, composer

I've got Craft 3.1.32 up and running on dev machines and we're ready to get it into our test/stage enviromnments, which are built through a GitLab CI/CD. While doing this, we noticed some plugins wouldn't install and would throw a composer error:

> `[RuntimeException]`
>   `craft/plugins/[plugin-name]/` does not exist and could not be created.

Now, `craft/plugins` is the Craft 2 location for plugins, and that directory doesn't exist in Craft 3, right? I see there's a file that gets created called `/vendor/composer/installers/src/Composer/Installers/CraftInstaller.php` that has a reference to `craft/plugins/{$name}` so I'm guessing that this file is being invoked to do some quick stuff to clean  the plugin name. But I'm not sure what the directory is really doing.

Any ideas?

EDIT:
It looks like there's a nice file within the `composer/composer` repo that dates back to Craft 2: [See CraftInstaller.php in GitHub](https://github.com/composer/installers/blob/master/src/Composer/Installers/CraftInstaller.php) that is pointing at old directories

Answer (score 4):

I found the real root cause. A internal business plugin which I migrated from Craft 2 to Craft 3 had a composer.json file which required `composer/installers` and that little bugger was mucking up the whole thing. 
So if you find that in your composer.lock file for Craft 3, go in deep and find it!